# Same github user two computers

Tags: git, github, workflow

Is any thing to take into account when using the same remote repo, same user and two different computers? for instance, desktop and laptop.

I guess, if I push before I pull last changes, because is the same user, will this changes be overwirtten? Or is git checking datestamps or something like that and it won't allow me to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will not allow you to push changes to a branch unless they can be resolved as a "fast-forward," which means that the tip commit you are trying to push is a direct descendant of the tip commit in the remote repository.  **Who made each set of changes is irrelevant** -- you just can't do it.<sup>1</sup>  In that respect, you are safe from clobbering work pushed from somewhere else by you *or someone else*.  You'll just get a harmless error message if you try.

How you deal with that error message is up to you.  Usually you will want to `git fetch` and then decide if you should merge or rebase.  (How to make that decision is out of the scope of your question.)

---

<sup>1</sup> You can override this check by supplying `--force` as an argument to the `git push` command, but you should not do this unless you understand exactly the implications of a non-fast-forward push.  It's semantically the same thing as doing a `git reset` on a local branch, which can discard history.  Use it with extreme caution.